# angular ng-model: changing the binding target dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following template:

```
<label for="chk-bl-{{item.Id}}" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <input type="{{inputType}}"
           id="chk-bl-{{apiController}}-{{item.Id}}"
           value="{{item.Id}}"
           ng-model="active[item.Id]"
           ng-true-value="{{item[nameField]}}" />

    {{item[nameField]}}
</label>
```

I want to be able to bind to `scope.active` when type=radio and to `scope.active[item.Id]` when type=checkbox. I tried `{{modelIdentifier()}}` but angular errors out saying it expects `[:]`.

Is there a way to do this without copying and pasting the underlying code and changing the template?

Comment: would use a directive and adjust template based on attributes

Comment: @charlietfl ok, so I did this. now angular throws the following error: `JavaScript runtime error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <div class="ng-scope" ng-transclude="">`. Transclusion is set to true and the code that compiles the template is `element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));`

Comment: create demo in plunker showing directive, shouldn't need `transclude` for basic input element

Comment: Yeah I ended up moving the transcluded functionality into the directive